# Перекрёстный запрос sql php

Tags: php, mysql, sql, phpmyadmin, запрос

Можете подсказать, пожалуйста, как мне вывести на странице в таблицу не id, которое в базе, а само значения, которое связано с другой таблицей.
К примеру, сейчас у меня вывод выглядит вот так:

```
№   Название датчика    Значение    Тип значения    Дата
1   1                    1                 1        2020-05-01 12:00:05
3   1                    5                 2        2020-05-01 00:00:00
4   1                    555               3        2020-05-21 00:00:00
8   1                    2                 1        2020-05-02 23:00:00
9   1                    3                 1        2020-05-05 00:04:00
10  1                    6                 1        2020-05-14 06:00:00
```

И запрос этот выглядит:

```
SELECT 
  `id_data`, 
  `data_id_model`, 
  `data_value`, 
  `data_id_type_value`, 
  `data_date`  
FROM `data_indicators` 
WHERE data_id_station = '".$_GET['id']."'
```

Можете подсказать, как мне вывести правильно чтобы были данные, а не id?

База:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Необходимо связать таблицы `data_indicators`, `models` (модели датчиков), `type_value` (имена парметров) по ключевым полям, они имеют пересечение в названии. В секцию `FROM` добавляются имена таблиц, в `WHERE` условия связи, после этого в `SELECT` можно использовать столбцы из добавленых таблиц.

```
SELECT 
  d.id_data, 
  m.model_name, 
  d.data_value, 
  t.type_value_name, 
  d.data_date  
FROM type_value t,
     models m,
     data_indicators d
WHERE d.data_id_station = '".$_GET['id']"'
AND   m.id_model = d.data_id_model
AND   t.id_type_value = d.data_id_type_value
```

Добавил еще имя параметра, хорошо бы еще вывести единицу измерения `type_value.type_value_unit`

Comment: Спасибо большое)) Добавила единицу измерения уже по аналогии